# How can I include icons in my ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I know that similar questions have already been asked here before, but they all lead to the [same codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/glistbox.aspx) that doesn't work. Does anybody know of a working ListBox with icons?

Comment: You should add a link to that CodeProject article.

Comment: And mention what doesn't work with the CodeProject article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will a `ListView` work for you? That is what I use. Much easier and you can make it look just like a `ListBox`. Also, plenty of documentation on MSDN to get started with.

> **How to: Display Icons for the Windows Forms ListView Control**
>   The Windows Forms ListView control can display icons from three image
>   lists. The List, Details, and SmallIcon views display images from the
>   image list specified in the SmallImageList property. The LargeIcon
>   view displays images from the image list specified in the
>   LargeImageList property. A list view can also display an additional
>   set of icons, set in the StateImageList property, next to the large or
>   small icons. For more information about image lists, see ImageList
>   Component (Windows Forms) and How to: Add or Remove Images with the
>   Windows Forms ImageList Component.

Inserted from [How to: Display Icons for the Windows Forms ListView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-icons-for-the-windows-forms-listview-control)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change ListBox to a ListView you can write a handler for DrawItemEvent. for example:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.listBox.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox_DrawItem);
    ...
 }
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index == -1)
            return;
        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();
        var rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X+10, e.Bounds.Y+8, 12, 14);
       //assuming the icon is already added to project resources
        e.Graphics.DrawIconUnstretched(YourProject.Properties.Resources.YouIcon, rect);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 25, e.Bounds.Y + 10, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

you can play around with the rectangle to set the location of the icon right

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck working in WinForms, then you'll have to owner-draw your items.

See the example for the [DrawItem event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A little different approach - don't use a list box.
Instead of using that control that bounds me to its limited set of properties and methods I am making a listbox of my own.

It's not as hard as it sounds:

```
int yPos = 0;    
Panel myListBox = new Panel();
foreach (Object object in YourObjectList)
{
    Panel line = new Panel();
    line.Location = new Point(0, Ypos);
    line.Size = new Size(myListBox.Width, 20);
    line.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(line_MouseClick);
    myListBox.Controls.Add(line);

    // Add and arrange the controls you want in the line

    yPos += line.Height;
}
```

Example for myListBox event handlers - selecting a line:

```
private void line_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs)
{
    foreach (Control control in myListBox.Controls)
        if (control is Panel)
            if (control == sender)
                control.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            else
                control.BackColor = Color.Transparent;      
}
```

The code samples above were not tested but the described method was used and found very convenient and simple.